# How to change host of a post request (proxy)

Tags: proxy

i want change the host url of a java applet. 
I just played around with the burp proxy but there is no "Match and replace" for the host url.
Instead of http://www.foo.com/abc/index.php?name=john the page http://www.bar.com/abc/index.php?name=john should be requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this through a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

[Apache supports reverse proxies](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies), though I find them to be a bit tricky to get working properly. Apache Reverse Proxies do offer quite a lot of control.

Another Reverse Proxy solution is "[Pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/)". I find Pound reasonably easy to configure and use, though it's less feature rich than Apache's options.

There are [many other](http://www.google.com/search?q=reverse%20proxy) reverse proxy solutions out there too. Some you can pay for, some even are implemented as hardware devices.